# No Data when using Mosaic to New Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, mosaic

I am using the Mosaic to New Raster tool in ArcMap 10.7.1 to mosaic 4 rasters shown below. I downloaded all of them from the [ArcticDEM](https://www.pgc.umn.edu/data/arcticdem/) dataset. They do not overlap and as far as I can tell they have identical properties (32 Bit float, same spatial reference, 32m cell size...) and only vary slightly in the range of pixel values.

[image]

When I use Mosaic to New Raster I get the following output. All the values from the top right raster now show as "No Data". I am not sure why this would be happening? Any suggestions?

[image]

EDIT: I ended up removing the offending raster and reloading it before running the mosaic tool again, and for some reason it was fine...

Comment: It's naughty tool, and slow. Just use cell statistics  maximum. Simply set env. Extent to union.